# Scrollbar and its content is hidden outside of div

Tags: html, css, scroll, height, overflow

So I have a problem where I have 2 divs inside of another div with a fixed size. I the second of the two is too large to fit in the fixed height div so I want a scroll bara to appear. But the scrollbar goes outside of the content. How do I fix this?

html:

```
<div class="main"> 
  <div class="first-child">
    <div class="small-content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
    <div class="large-content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.main {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.first-child {
  background-color: red;
}

.second-child {
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.large-content {
  padding-top: 300px;
}

.small-content {
  padding: 10px;

}
```

https://codepen.io/RilleJ/pen/JeBVpz

I added an example as well to show what I mean. Basically I want to be able to scroll all the way down in the blue box and see the content without setting a fixed height. (Not that the content above, the red box, can be different sizes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use flexbox to divide the space of the container among the children.
- Add flex-grow: 0, and flex-shrink: 0 for a child that just needs to take the space it needs for its content.
- Add flex-grow: 1, and flex-shrink: 1 on the other children to divide the remaining space equally (each child will take at least the size of its content).

```css
.main {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first-child {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.second-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.large-content {
  padding-top: 300px;
}

.small-content {
  padding: 10px;

}
```

```html
<div class="main"> 
  <div class="first-child">
    <div class="small-content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
    <div class="large-content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this solves the problem if the page is loaded once with content that is static. But as I said in the end, the red content can be dynamic and isn't always 38px.